# C# Cannot change static fields in static generic class

Tags: c#, generics, unity-game-engine, null

This is in the Unity Game engine, although I am not sure if this is a c# thing or just Unity specific.

```
//This is fine, I can assign variables to these static fields as you would expect
public static class Test
{
    public static List list = new List();
    public static int d = 0;
}

//Field in this class are always default, even after assigning values in another class
public static class Test<T>
{
    public static List<T> list = new List<T>();
    public static int d = 0;
}

public class TestClass2: MonoBehaviour
{
    private void TestMethod()
    {
         Test<int>.d = 3;
         Test<string>.list.Add("Hi");
         //Both are still null, even after declaring and assigning
    }
}
```

Can someone explain to me why `Test<int>.d` is still `0` and `List` is null after assigning values?

Comment: You would need to assign this in static constructor.

Comment: If `list` were `null`, you would get a `NullReferenceException` when you call `Add`.

Comment: An `int` can't be null, so your question is based on false assumptions.

Comment: You are wrong and mistaking.

Comment: this might be helpful:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: @JerrySwitalski `list` and `d` are being assigned in the static constructor. That's how initializers on fields are compiled. @Dennis_E whether or not a `NullReferenceException` is thrown does not address the question. @Martin Mazza Dawson `Test<int>.d` is not still zero. It is 3.

Comment: @Nick you are right, thanks

Comment: There's no need to answer or comment on extremely basic questions that should not be on the site, just close.  **Clutter will kill the "Unity" tag on this site** .. just like answers.unity3d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code works for me.

```
 Test<int>.d = 17;
 int seventeen = Test<int>.d;
```

Keep in mind `Test` and `Test<T>` are not the same thing you are only assigning an int value to `Test<int>.d`.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. When I hovered over the intellisence for Test<int>.d it's still 0.

But when assigning it to seventeen variable it does work. I don't know why this is.

Comment: This is because static member variables are not initialized until the first time they are accessed

Comment: @MartinMazzaDawson Did you set a breakpoint on the first line? If so, it hasn't executed yet and at that point, d is still 0.

Comment: @Dennis_E Even when stepping through the code fully, my intellisence said it's still 0, but assigning this to int seventeen gives the variable the correct value of 17.

I presume it's a bug in Intellisence when using Unity.